# Configure Angular 4.5 route to accept Azure B2C reply URL Authentication Token

Tags: angular, azure, azure-authentication

I am working on Angular 4.5 application which I need to authenticate using Azure-B2C. I have done the authentication but I am getting one error or another on reply Url configuration in azure

I have route setup in Angular app as http://localhost:4000/#/app/dashboard
this is default route that always called as home

```
 import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
 import { Layout } from './layout.component';

 const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: Layout, children: [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },

]}
];

     export const ROUTES = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

### scenario one error

if I setup in Azure --> application 'Reply URL' http://localhost:4000 the I managed to get Azure login page but the throw error after signing in as azure cannot find return url. which is normally as

http://localhost:4000/#state=

### Scenario two error

if I setup reply url http://localhost:4000/#/app/dashboard then it don't find login page from azure

I need help to configure route for Azure to response back with auth token.

any suggestion will be great regarding to routing

Comment: The reply URL for web apps and services must begin with the scheme `https`, NOT `http`

Comment: I am using localhost for testing and developing... B2C Azure works http but my main issue is configuring routing in angular to accept by Azure reply URL

Comment: I need to configure Angular route to be accepted by Azure B2C reply URL

Comment: @toxic were you able to find out a solution for this?